# reactjs setState is not a function on a JSON call

Tags: reactjs

What is wrong with my code?
I have an error when I get JSON from an API:

> this.setState is not a function

Code:

```
class App extends React.Component {

   constructor(props) {
      super(props);

      this.state = {
         data: []
      }
   };

   componentWillMount() {

      const url = 'myurl';

      http.get(url, function(res){
         var body = '';

         res.on('data', function(chunk){

            body += chunk;

         });

         res.on('end', function(){

            var res = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(res);
            this.setState({data: res});

         }.bind(this));

      }).on('error', function(e){
            console.log("Got an error: ", e);
      });
   }
}
```

Comment: Hint #1: `console.log(this);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are doing the correct thing by `bind`ing your 'end' method, however, you will need to do the same thing for your outer http.get method:

```
http.get(url, function(res){
 var body = '';

 res.on('data', function(chunk){

    body += chunk;

 });

 res.on('end', function(){

    var res = JSON.parse(body);
    console.log(res);
    this.setState({data: res});

 }.bind(this));

}.bind(this))
```

Comment: Thank you very much

Answer (score 1):

You can also use this way

```
class App extends React.Component {

constructor(props) {
    super(props);

    this.state = {
        data: []
    }
};

componentWillMount() {
    var self = this;
    const url = 'myurl';

    http.get(url, function (res) {
        var body = '';
        res.on('data', function (chunk) {
            body += chunk;
        });

        res.on('end', function () {
            var res = JSON.parse(body);
            console.log(res);
            self.setState({ data: res });

        })

    }).on('error', function (e) {
        console.log("Got an error: ", e);
    });
}}
```